# IEx Pry: Always allow / take over without prompt

Tags: elixir, pry, elixir-iex

When I run Elixir code with my debugger, Pry, then it always confronts me with `Allow? [Yn]`

1. Can I pass a configuration option to *always* allow this? Thus,
   by default?
2. Why is this question asked? What could be harmful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot provide an option to allow without manual confirmation.

The confirmation is a reused component of IEx, any terminal takeover messages (`:take`) [require user confirmation](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/f2bc1801127d4107e4e78d17b899a69699615bbb/lib/iex/lib/iex/server.ex#L106-L108). This take over flow [also happens in `IEx.pry/0`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/7340ca2d925297e98dd71528a09bf0fb8634b47f/lib/iex/lib/iex/pry.ex#L55).

As for why this is the case, I am not sure. I would assume it is a security measure. However, the confirmation simply safeguards [`IEx.evaluator.run/4`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/f2bc1801127d4107e4e78d17b899a69699615bbb/lib/iex/lib/iex/server.ex#L127-L134), which does not seem to be an obvious attack vector.